# Sending Attachment to SAP B1 remote Service Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, erp, sapb1

In a C# application, I want to send files to "remote SAP B1 service layer". I have tried many ways to send an attachment to this remote service layer, using their b1s/v1/Attachments2 endpoint, but I continuously receive an error **"A file with this name already exists.  [Attachments2_Lines.FileName][line: 1], "**. Even this file does not exists in the service layer shared directory.
Moreover, I do have the read/write permissions in the destination path.
[image]

**Any Kind of help will be highly appreciated.**

Comment: In the c# code, I get 
-- error code 404
-- error message Create File Error: C:\tmp

Comment: Please don't use `sap` tag as per the guidelines ("DO NOT USE THIS TAG as it's ambiguous"; the reason is the same as for Microsoft and other software vendors, "microsoft" tag doesn't exist) The tag `sapb1` is sufficient. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue when adding attachments to a document. Try to send a GET and retrieve all records for /Attachments2. If the file was added before there might already exist a record having the same filename.

To add it again, you need to call a DELETE on the specific ID first, then POST it again.

Comment: No such file with the same name exists in Attachment2 directory. Even I have tried renaming the file to some random characters. But it throws same error.

Comment: There might exist no file in the actual physical director, but Service Layer maybe still have a record on that file. Therefore I suggested that you try to send a GET to /Attachments2 and retrieve *all* records. In the result you can check for your file to be present.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, and is there a good way to GET the newest attachments from the /Attachments2 endpoint?